# Mulberry bleeding for a month

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, pruning, mulberry

When I got my mulberry plant 8 months ago, it has two main branches. I wanted only 1 main branch. So removed one branch before planting. But the way I have removed the branch was, I left 1.5 inch from the trunk. It worked nicely.

Recently, I decided to remove that extra 1.5 inch. So I have removed that 1.5 inch. But it has been bleeding for a month and didn't heal completely. Can I help it somehow?

[image: mulberry tree after pruning]

[image: mulberry tree after pruning]

[image: mulberry tree after pruning]

[image: mulberry tree after pruning]

Update Jan 1, 2023:
the good news it has stopped bleeding after about 5 weeks.

[image: mulberry tree]

Comment: Not helpful to you now but if you have a large branch like that, the trick is to prune away its branches to slow its growth.  Then once the trunk has grown so that the branch's diameter is less than 1/4 of the trunk diameter, you can remove it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to be hard:  the best thing to do for pruning is: nothing.

There is enough of a collar around the cut that, with time, the tissue around the perimeter of the cut will heal over and close off.  You are seeing sap continue to come out as I expect it is hot enough that the tree is transpiring water from the roots to the leaves at full speed.

The best things you can do are:

- provide water during hot and dry periods (less frequent waterings of ten litres of more are preferred over frequent, small volumes)
- top dress with organic matter or compost  ( 1 cm per application every few months)

Here is [another article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286331397_Tree_pruning_A_modern_approach) that is very detailed on how to prune for trees of all ages

Comment: Ok. I see that its leaves started to dry like this https://ibb.co/YhnFb1B . I believe enough water wasn't going up. But now, the good news it has stopped bleeding after about 5 weeks. https://ibb.co/93p2W7Z & https://ibb.co/ZgqyX6t

Comment: Now it has started to bleed again as new growth and fruiting has started. Bleeding is slightly less than the above, but it is happening.

Comment: Update: tree has started to lose unripe fruits everyday. Almost 80% fruits have fallen down. Growth of leaves that started very fast has become very slow as weather is also becoming a little hot. During day, when temperate is about 31c, all leaves curl up. At night they relax. A few new branches heads have dried up. Here temperature goes upto 50c. I don't know what will it do then. I will share photos later, but I am thinking, maybe kill it and plant a new tree. This is taking too long to heal. @kevinskio

Comment: I have same tree a little away in same soil, with same water and sun, it is growing like crazy. because it has no wound. However, it was planted a few months earlier relative to wounded tree.

Comment: @EresDev  fruit drop is frequently associated with not enough water.  Is the soil too porous?  Drains too quickly or not at all?

Comment: Yes, it is sandy. So, I water every 2nd or 3rd day. I check it using 2 tools plus hands. I am keep it very appropriate. I give same amount of water to other tree I talked about. @kevinskio

Comment: My theory is the water that is supposed to go up, is flowing through the wound. Though the bleeding is not so sever as it was before.